# Unable to upload new APK file to Android Play store

Tags: android, google-play

I'm getting below error while trying to upload new APK file.

> Upload failed
>
> You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to
>   disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play.

Comment: Did you post a debuggable build?

Comment: This should probably help you http://sreedevr.wordpress.com/2013/10/28/exporting-a-signed-apk-to-upload-android/

Comment: Android Studio, menu "View", "Tool Windows", "Build Variants".

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In my case I had to add  android:debuggable="false" into manifest.. Worked even without few days ago.

Comment: It looks like Google is FINALLY blocking apps that have the debuggable flag set to TRUE on release builds. About bloody time.

Comment: Be sure to add the android:debuggable="false" in the application tag of the manifest file. If you add in the manifest tag it will not work.

Comment: Interesting.  This implies that the [docs for this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#debug) may be incorrect.

Comment: Avoid to hardcoding debug mode warning. Something about it?

Comment: Lint will warn you. You have to export `signed / un-signed apk` from Android tools in project properties in eclipse. Never use a build generated in `project/bin` directory for production. **This answer is no correct at all.**

Answer (score 59):

If you're using Android Studio, the simplest way is to open the "Build Variant" toolbar on the left bottom and change it from "Debug" to "Release" then "Build" -> "Generated Signed APK".

Comment: Mine was at the left bottom. It tooks me a while to find it :)

Comment: So was mine, not sure why I originally wrote "Right". Fixed now, thanks :-)

Comment: That should be the right answer. Putting android:debuggable to false gives a warning.

Comment: This is the correct way if you are using Android Studio!

Comment: Works perfectly for Android Studio.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you have a sub module that declares android:debuggable="true" in it's manifest application tag, the apk will be debugable even when using this method. And the play store will reject it.

Answer (score 0):

If you using maven and android-maven-plugin, add this to plugin configuration

```
 <configuration>
   <release>true</release>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you know if all new Android Studio projects by default are created with maven and maven-plugin or does a dev always add those into a project?  And where would I find the plugin configuration in Android Studio, in the build gradle section?

Answer (score 0):

Please note, even if you have a release entry in your gradle build with debuggable false, if debuggable is set to true in the AndroidManifest.xml, it will still fail to upload. Found a random subproject in mine that had it set to true even though the gradle build file was false for all sub projects.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still looking the answer. I had similar problem. In my case Google Api error was: `Google Api Error: apkNotificationMessageKeyDebuggable: APK is marked as debuggable. - APK is marked as debuggable.` During investigation I've found that inside `BuildConfig.java` file `DEBUG` constant equals `true` even though `BUILD_TYPE == release`. After several hours I've found [this thread](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/qualitymatters/issues/180). So in my case the problem was in jacoco. After removing `testCoverageEnabled = true` for release build, `DEBUG` became `false` again.