# Cant upload APK to googleplay?

Tags: java, android, apk, android-install-apk

Hi i get this error message when trying to upload APK to Google Play:

Upload failed
You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play

I used eclipse before and am sure I am just not doing something simple if anyone can help me out...

Answer (score -1):

The normal way to upload your APK to Google Play is as follows:

1. Go to Eclipse and right click on your app root
2. Select Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package
3. Save the APK in a different folder (I have a release folder)
4. Upload the APK to google.

For more details, you should have a look at [Google docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html"Information about signing and publishing APK") for publishing. You also will have to sign the package, hence you have to get a key.

Comment: and for android studio?

Comment: "If you're using Android Studio, the simplest way is to open the "Build Variant" toolbar on the left bottom and change it from "Debug" to "Release" then "Build" -> "Generated Signed APK"."

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994874/unable-to-upload-new-apk-file-to-android-play-store