# I got zip aligned error

Tags: android, apk, zipalign

I have an apk finished, when I tried to upload it, I get an error of zipalign, I tried to fix it but I didn't know how!
The line is

```
zipalign [-f] [-v] <alignment> infile.apk outfile.apk
```

Let's say I have mine.apk and I have zipalign.exe in my laptop, can someone please tell me what to type? I tried many things!

Comment: Check this link - http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html

Comment: how you ever seen this post before : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333724/how-to-zip-align-apk-file-in-android

Comment: I did, I changed alignment to mine (apk) .. infile.apk to mine1.apk ... outfile.apk to mine.apk, it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

open command prompt in directory of zipalign.exe (found in sdk/build-tools/)

the command I use is:

```
zipalign -v 4 "<apk>" "<apk-zipaligned>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
zipalign.exe -v 4  mine.apk  mine_out.apk
```

v is for verbose output,4 provides 32-bit alignment

The mine_out.apk is the the output file.

**EDIT:**

Add your `android:debuggable="false"` linke this:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:debuggable="false">
```

Comment: It worked but gave me another error "You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play."

Comment: @Sahar, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994874/unable-to-upload-new-apk-file-to-android-play-store

Comment: I just added false in android:debuggable="false" into manifest .. it gave me an error line! :(

Comment: @Sahar It should not be an error, clean your project and build it again please.

Answer (score 0):

zipalign -v 4 c:/ad/shilo_release_unsigned.apk c:/ad/shilo_release_ready.apk
The command prompt should return a success message "Verification successful".

Comment: It's fixed as mentioned in the previous post, I got another error!

Comment: what is the another one?